# Ubuntu and the "immortal" grub

Tags: grub2

Until yesterday on my minipc all works fine,system boot and works.
After hibernate I reboot and...the bootloader "refind" disappear and magically appear a grub shell!

So i do..

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15
initrd /boot/initramfs-4.15..
boot
```

And go only to initramfs shell,which said
"cannot mount /dev/ on /root/dev.."

I reboot to a ubuntu livecd..

```
fsck -c /dev/mmcblkp1
fsck -c /dev/mmcblkp2
```

Give no error.

I make a chroot(of course mounting dev,proc,sys,with bind)
reinstall refind with

```
refind-install --usedefault /dev/mmblkp1
```

said to me "no problem",but on reboot...still the grub shell!

I return to ubuntu livecd,destroy and recreate efi partition with the same size,then redo chroot,reinstall refind and..
grub-shell.

What happened?Now I try to reinstall grub and make a grub menu..
but if I want to use refind,why grub still live and even with dd=/dev/zero on efi partition cannot remove?

System is: 
ubuntu is: 17.10 
grub is: efi,boot mode is UEFI

Comment: Perhaps you have a legacy grub in the MBR and you are not booting in UEFI mode?

Comment: Grub is efi,boot mode is UEFI,I edit now my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I found the solutions: the system had two "boot partition"

```
dev/mmcblk1boot0
dev/mmcblk1boot1
```

For overwrite them I need

```
echo 0 >  /sys/block/mmcblk1boot0/force_ro
```

And then try to reinstall refind

Another solution is: reinstall ubuntu and then recover from backup